# Insert/Edit records using php and javascript/ajax

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I'm trying to make user interface to edit/insert records and i'm having some troubles with my code.

Lists the records :

```
while ($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
            extract($row);
             $html.="<tr>


     <td style>{$row['name']}<input type='hidden' id='id' value='$row[a_id]'></td>
<td>{$row['season']}</td>
         <td><a href='edit1/new' id='edit'></a></td>
          <tr style='height: 5px;'></tr>
                </tr>..
```

Now the js that i`m having trubles with:

```
 <script type='text/javascript'>
$('#edit').on( 'click', function () {
 var x = document.getElementById('id').value;
      $.ajax({

             type: 'post',
             url: 'insert_edit.php',
             data: {
             id: x
             },
             success: function( data ) {
             console.log( data );
             }
             });
             });
</script>
```

inside the insert_edit.php

```
 if(isset($_POST['id'])){
        $html = Edit();
        }else{
        $html = Add();

    }
```

For some reason the on click function doesnt seem to work and it doesn`t posts data`insert_edit.php`

Any help will be apriciated thank you.

NOTE: I'm not sure even if the posts works I'm using the Java Script the right way since my while loop prints it foreach ID and my guess is even it if it posts the data it will aways posts the value of the first record.

Comment: `id: x` should be `'id': v`

Comment: Ids are meant to be unique !!!

Comment: Please remove the  href='edit1/new' and don't set href attribute pointing to any url because you are adding onclick event to a tag

Comment: Adding to @PatsyIssa's comment, if you have this repeating several times use `class` attribute instead. And then some more code to get the value of the closest hidden input. That one should be `class` too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to fix it. Here is how I did it:

1. I made an array $urlparts wich is my permalinks.
2. The button code goes like this

> ..a href='/account/competitions/edit1/update/$row[a_id]'>Edit..

1. And some php

> ```
> if (isset($urlparts[4]) && is_numeric($urlparts[4])){
>       require_once ("insert_edit.php");
>       $html = Edit();
>       }
> ```

and inside the Edit();
just snach the id with

> $id = $urlparts[4];

Thank you for the feeedback guys. Made me realize that I`m looking at the issue from the wrong angle:)

Answer (score 0):

Try this- on click function replace with this-

```
$(document).on("click", "#edit", function(){
   // ..
})
```